How do I perform an RP initiated logout in Liberty?
I'm using an <openidConnectClient> in my server.xml to configure authentication for my applications. When the user logs out of my application, I'd also like it to log out of the OP, and I don't mind if that's by a background POST to the logout endpoint, or by redirecting the user (See the spec at https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-rpinitiated-1_0.html).
What's the right approach here? I feel like my application shouldn't need to understand OIDC RP-Initiated logout to do it, because that layer is handled by Liberty. Is there a standard logout call I can make in my servlet that will trigger RP-Initiated logout? Is there a way to configure it so that the standard HttpServletRequest.logout() method will also trigger the RP-Initiated logout for the user? Am I going about it the wrong way?
